# From what Star Trek script was Sasheer Zamata's name taken from, and what was the original spelling?

Tags: star-trek, character-identification, episode-identification

In the *The Late Show with Stephen Colbert* video [Sasheer Zamata Is A Tough Name For Certain People](https://youtu.be/O53ztzsOW_w) after about `02:00` the comedienne says:

> …my name doesn’t come from any African or island culture. It’s from Star Trek. My parents are trekkies. And they were really into trekkie culture.
>
> My mom found the original script where my name comes from, and realized that my parents accidentally misspelled my name.

**Question:** From what Star Trek script was Sasheer Zamata's name taken from, and what was the original spelling?

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Sahsheer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is from [TOS: By Any Other Name](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/By_Any_Other_Name_(episode)). Zamata described the circumstances a bit more clearly in [this interview](https://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=523684973&t=1532864840198)

> **ZAMATA:** *...Captain Kirk was flirting with this alien princess, as he does. And he gave her a rose. And she goes, oh, we have something like this on my planet except it's made out of crystal and it's called Sasheer. And my parents were like yes...*

And we can see the correct spelling in the Blish novelisation of the episode (based on the original script).

> “Flowers,” he said, moving closer to her, cautiously. “I don’t know the variety.”
>
> “Our memory tapes tell us of such things on Kelva,” Rojan said.
> “Crystals which form with such rapidity that they seem to grow. They look like these; fragile things, somewhat. We call them **‘sahsheer.**’”
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek 6: By Any Other Name](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek_6)</sup></sub>

Interestingly sahsheer crystals receive a name-check in the EU novel [Aftermath](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/g00/wiki/Aftermath?i10c.encReferrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvLnVrLw%3D%3D&i10c.ua=1&i10c.dv=14) ***despite being native to another galaxy***.

> “That’s the part of war people don’t talk about much. Sure, the loss of life is horrible—the Breen took a lot of my friends that day. And the property losses, okay, those are bad too. But it’s a damn sight easier to rebuild a lecture hall or an office complex than it is to regrow a Gordian oak or a sahsheer crystal."

Comment: I certainly remember the episode, but I don't recall this scene. I'll have to go look it up, thanks!